# Liquid script support

Tags: email, liquid

I'm trying to get a liquid script to run and it doesnt seem to be working at all.
The script detects if an address is cc'd in an incoming email and then launches a template.

My script looks like this

```
{% assign templates = "" %}

{% for cc in ticket.ccs %}
  {% if cc.email == "EMAIL 1" %}
    {% assign templates = templates | append: "template-ID," %}
  {% endif %}  
  {% if cc.email == "EMAIL_2" %}
    {% assign templates = templates | append: "template-ID2," %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if templates != "" %}
  {{ templates }}
{% else %}
  Test
{% endif %}
```

The idea is that if I receive an email to any address, and email 1 or email 2 are cc'd, I want to automatically launch my template for any cc'd adress.

I tried having a template that simply changed the email title. With all my test, the title never changed. Seems to me that either the cc's are not detected, or the template doesn't launch.

anyone has an idea?